# Delete on Many to Many Relationship using Fluent Nhibernatev

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, sharp-architecture

Please, help me! I can't delete objects and dependence in  Oid and CertRequest table.

I have follow:

Oid

public class Oid
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual int RowVersion { get; set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

```
public class OidMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Oid>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Oid> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(c => c.Code).Not.Nullable().Unique();
        mapping.Map(c => c.Name).Not.Nullable().Length2000();
    }
}
```

CertRequest

```
public class CertRequest
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }  
    public virtual int RowVersion { get; set; }      
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Oid> Oids { get; set; }
}

public class CertRequestMap : IAutoMappingOverride<CertRequest>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<CertRequest> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(c => c.LastName).Nullable().Length2000();
        mapping.Map(c => c.FirstName).Nullable().Length2000();
        mapping.Map(c => c.MiddleName).Nullable().Length2000();
        mapping.HasManyToMany(c => c.Oids)
            .Table("CertRequestToOid")
            .ParentKeyColumn("CertRequestId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("OidId");
    }
}
```

Deleting code:

```
certRequest.Oids.Clear();

_certRequestRepository.SaveOrUpdate(certRequest);

_certRequestRepository.Delete(certRequest);
```

Do nothing.

Any tip...

**UPDATE**

I am sorry, i not said that i use Sharp-Architecture, and Transaction attribute on method.

Comment: Me help do all operations in one transaction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `_certRequestRepository` an object of type `ISession`?

If so, you will have to call `_certRequestRepository.Flush()` to commit the delete to the database.

Better yet, use a Transaction.

```
using(var transaction = _certRequestRepository.BeginTransaction())
{
    certRequest.Oids.Clear();
    certRequestRepository.Delete(certRequest);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, i not said that i use Sharp-Architecture, and Transaction attribute on method.